# Php-unit tests - is not fetching the $user object

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm writting some tests for a web application, and one of them  is Failing when in production & development is working fine.

That's the fail:

> myMelomanBundle\Publication\CreatePublicationUseCaseTest::shouldCreateAPublicationOneTimeIfItDoesNotExist
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to myDomain\Entity\Publication::setUser() must be an instance of myDomain\Entity\User, null given, called in /var/www/melomaniacs/src/myDomain/UseCases/Publication/CreatePublicationUseCase.php on line 48

CreatePublicationUseCaseTest.php:

```
<?php

namespace myMelomanBundle\Publication;

use myDomain\Entity\Publication;
use myDomain\UseCases\Publication\CreatePublicationUseCase;
use myMelomanBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
use myMelomanBundle\Repository\PublicationRepository;
use PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use myDomain\Entity\User;

class CreatePublicationUseCaseTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
const USER_ID   = 2;
const MESSAGE   = "message";
const URI       = "spotify:uri:47n4in3482nk";

/**
 * @var CreatePublicationUseCase
 */
private $createPublicationUseCase;

/**
 * @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 */
private $userRepositoryMock;

/**
 * @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 */
private $publicationRepositoryMock;

/**
 * @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 */
private $aDispatcherMock;

/**
 * @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 */
private $aEntityMock;

/**
 * @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 */
private $userMock;


protected function setUp()
{

    $this->userRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);
    $this->publicationRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(PublicationRepository::class);
    $this->aEntityMock = $this->createMock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
    $this->createPublicationUseCase = new CreatePublicationUseCase($this->publicationRepositoryMock, $this->userRepositoryMock, $this->aEntityMock);
    $this->userMock = $this->createMock(User::class);

}

protected function tearDown()
{
    $this->userRepositoryMock = null;
    $this->publicationRepositoryMock = null;
    $this->createPublicationUseCase = null;
    $this->userMock = null;
}

/** @test */
public function dummyTest()
{
    $this->createPublicationUseCase;
}

/** @test */
public function shouldCreateAPublicationOneTimeIfItDoesNotExist()
{
    $this->givenAPublicationRepositoryThatDoesNotHaveASpecificPublication();
    $this->thenThePublicationShouldBeSavedOnce();
    $this->whenTheCreateUserUseCaseIsExecutedWithASpecificParameters();

}

private function givenAPublicationRepositoryThatDoesNotHaveASpecificPublication()
{
    $this->publicationRepositoryMock
        ->method('find')
        ->willReturn(false);
}

private function thenThePublicationShouldBeSavedOnce()
{
    $this->publicationRepositoryMock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('create')
        ->willReturn($this->isInstanceOf(Publication::class));
}

private function whenTheCreateUserUseCaseIsExecutedWithASpecificParameters()
{
    $this->createPublicationUseCase->execute(self::USER_ID, self::MESSAGE, null);
}
}
```

CreatePublicationUseCase.php

```
<?php

namespace myDomain\UseCases\Publication;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use myDomain\Entity\Publication;
use myDomain\Entity\User;
use myDomain\PublicationRepositoryInterface;
use myDomain\UserRepositoryInterface;
use myMelomanBundle\Repository\PublicationRepository;
use myMelomanBundle\Repository\UserRepository;

class CreatePublicationUseCase
{
/**
 * @var PublicationRepository
 */
private $publicationRepository;

/**
 * @var UserRepository
 */
private $userRepository;
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(
    PublicationRepositoryInterface $publicationRepository,
    UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository,
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
)
{
    $this->publicationRepository = $publicationRepository;
    $this->userRepository        = $userRepository;
    $this->entityManager         = $entityManager;
}

public function execute($userId, $message = null, $uri = null)
{
    try{
        /**
         * @var User $user
         */
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(array('id'=>$userId));

        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user);die; => Here

        $publication = new Publication();
        $publication->setMessage($message == null ? '' : $message);
        $publication->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $publication->setUser($user);
        $publication->setStatus(0);
        $publication->setLink($uri == null ? '' : $uri);
        $this->publicationRepository->create($publication);

        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $publication;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Note that where is the dump , it returns the user object properly, just on the Test it's returning NULL.

On the test, it should be getting to me same User object result that without the test, shouldn't be?

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're mocking the `findOneBy()` call of the user repository, or am I missing something.

Comment: Thanks @JasonRoman. Yes, I was missing call userRepositoryMock for findOneBy()! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue is coming from the following line from `CreatePublicationUseCase::execute`

```
$user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(array('id'=>$userId));
```

In your test, you pass in a mocked `UserRepository` but you don't mock the output of `findOneBy`.

```
$this->userRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);
```

I believe you will have the results you want if you also mock the results with something like the following.

```
$this->userRepositoryMock
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('findOneBy')
    ->will($this->returnValue(<value>));
```

Comment: Thanks @PhiloEpisteme! You are right. I had to add: private function thenTheUserRepositoryShouldFindAUser() {
        $this->userRepositoryMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('findOneBy')
            ->willReturn($this->userMock);
    }
Thank you! :)